No tests to run
I am attempting to run a test on one file with forge test --match-path test/DonutBurger.t.sol  but I get No tests to run despite being able to run forge test successfully.
Any ideas?
 $ forge test
[⠊] Compiling...
[⠒] Compiling 4 files with 0.8.24
[⠢] Solc 0.8.24 finished in 985.19ms
Compiler run successful!

Ran 2 tests for test/DonutBurger.t.sol:DonutBurgerTest
[PASS] testFuzz_SetNumber(uint256) (runs: 256, μ: 30532, ~: 31310)
[PASS] test_Increment() (gas: 31325)
Suite result: ok. 2 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 7.90ms (7.72ms CPU time)

Ran 2 tests for test/Counter.t.sol:CounterTest
[PASS] testFuzz_SetNumber(uint256) (runs: 256, μ: 30610, ~: 31310)
[PASS] test_Increment() (gas: 31325)
Suite result: ok. 2 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 7.96ms (7.78ms CPU time)

Ran 2 test suites in 8.44ms (15.86ms CPU time): 4 tests passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped (4 total tests)

$ ls test
Counter.t.sol  DonutBurger.t.sol

$ ls src
Counter.sol  DonutBurger.sol

$ forge --version
forge 0.2.0 (1281421 2024-04-05T00:17:33.105023260Z)

$ forge test --match-path test/DonutBurger.t.sol 
No tests match the provided pattern:
        match-path: `test/DonutBurger.t.sol`
Error: 
No tests to run
$ forge test --match-path ./test/Counter.t.sol 
No tests match the provided pattern:
        match-path: `./test/Counter.t.sol`
Error: 
No tests to run

One of the Solidity files here:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract DonutBurger {
    uint256 public number;

    function setNumber(uint256 newNumber) public {
        number = newNumber;
    }

    function increment() public {
        number++;
    }
}

And the Solidity test files here:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {DonutBurger} from "../src/DonutBurger.sol";

contract DonutBurgerTest is Test {
    DonutBurger public donutBurger;

    function setUp() public {
        donutBurger = new DonutBurger();
        donutBurger.setNumber(0);
    }

    function test_Increment() public {
        donutBurger.increment();
        assertEq(donutBurger.number(), 1);
    }

    function testFuzz_SetNumber(uint256 x) public {
        donutBurger.setNumber(x);
        assertEq(donutBurger.number(), x);
    }
}


I've executed your code. Running tests via --match-path to filter test files on forge test are working fine.
Here's the output:
forge test --match-path test/DonutBurger.t.sol


forge test --match-path test/Counter.t.sol


You should try running this command to update/fix any issues in your current foundry installation:
foundryup

And then, re-run the --match-path commands.
P.S. You can also check other commands to filter tests, if they're working fine on your end or not:

To filter test contracts:
forge test --match-contract DonutBurgerTest

forge test --match-contract CounterTest


To filter test functions:
forge test --match-test test_Increment

forge test --match-test testFuzz_SetNumber



